# touches-canceled vs. touchesCancelled

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There is a method for touch events in iOS called `touchesCancelled`. I asked a question related to it, and I noticed there was a tag [touches-canceled](/questions/tagged/touches-canceled).

There was no [touchescancelled](/questions/tagged/touchescancelled) tag. Was I wrong to use [touches-canceled](/questions/tagged/touches-canceled)?

Does it maybe reference something non-iOS?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How did you make the tag boxes?

Comment: By writing \[tag:touches-canceled] - it's in the revision history. =)

Comment: Am I missing something about iOS, or should those questions all be retagged to use the correct spelling?

Comment: @PopularDemand I certainly hope so!

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure the `touchesCancelled` method is notable enough to deserve its own tag. Again, I don't know anything about iOS, but the tag has only been used seven times, and `touchesCancelled` [only appears 369 times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=touchescancelled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all but one of the questions is also tagged with [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) and/or [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), I'd say that's the intended purpose of that tag.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could have browsed through those.